# I do not know how to make this pattern, its not done by rotate , as outline show no line as attachment

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I  do not know how to make this pattern in ILLUSTRATOR, its not done by rotate , as outline show no line as attachment  thanks

[image]

[image]

---

joojaa- thanks, that's one of the method 
Cai -- Yes , I think that's a transform effect as there's

[image]

no outline in the images, I tried to use the tranform effect but cannot accure fix the move & scale column . do you have any idea hoew to fix it ?
erickp -- definelly its not done by rotate as theres no online at the images

Comment: And why do you think this is not rotated?

Comment: It's probably a transform effect.

Answer (score 6):

You could construct it via an arrangement of circles.

1. Start with a circle that is for example 10 mm in diameter
2. Copy it and position the second circle's center on the edge of the
   first one
3. Copy the first circle again and move it -2.5 mm vertically and 4.33
   mm horizontally
4. Copy the third circle and move it -8.66 mm horizontally
5. Arrange the remaining 3 circles around your base circle
6. Select all circles and build the pattern via the shape builder tool
   [image: creating circle pattern]

Comment: Offcourse rotating around the lower point by  by would eliminate quite much construction time and produce less control points.